# how to resolve Cloud Signing permission error in xcode

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, flutter, xcode

I couldn't make an IOS build in XCode because of the error **Cloud Signing permission error in XCode** Please help
[image]

Comment: Please add your picture and post your full error

Comment: check i have added the image

Answer (score 0):

The "Cloud Signing permission error" in Xcode typically occurs when you're trying to build and sign an iOS app using a provisioning profile associated with an Apple developer account that does not have the necessary permissions. To resolve this issue, you can try the following steps:

Verify Developer Account Permissions: Make sure that the Apple developer account you're using has the necessary permissions for code signing. Check if you have the appropriate roles and access to certificates, identifiers, and provisioning profiles.
Refresh Account in Xcode: Open Xcode and go to Preferences by clicking on "Xcode" in the menu bar and selecting "Preferences." Navigate to the "Accounts" tab and select your Apple developer account. Click on the "–" button to remove the account, and then click on the "+" button to add it back. This will refresh the account credentials in Xcode.
Update Xcode: Ensure that you are using the latest version of Xcode. Go to the App Store and check for any available updates for Xcode. Keeping Xcode up to date can help resolve compatibility issues and provide bug fixes.
Reset Keychain: In some cases, the issue may be related to a problem with the keychain. You can try resetting the keychain by opening "Keychain Access" from the "Utilities" folder within the "Applications" folder. From the "Keychain Access" menu, select "Keychain Access" > "Preferences," and then click on the "Reset My Default Keychain" button. Keep in mind that this action will remove all your saved passwords, so make sure to have backups if necessary.
Revoke and Regenerate Certificates: If the above steps don't work, you can try revoking and regenerating your certificates, provisioning profiles, and App IDs in the Apple Developer portal. This process can help ensure that you have valid and properly configured code signing assets.
If the issue persists after trying these steps, it might be helpful to provide more specific details about the error message or any related log output. That way, I can assist you with a more targeted solution.**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).